# How to set frameset row property using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to  set frameset row property into different browsers using css or jquery?

Comment: This is easy, don't use framesets, noone has been using those since the late eighties

Comment: @adeneo — The frame element wasn't introduced until 1996

Answer (score 1):

You can't set it with CSS.

With jQuery you can use [the `attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). I don't know how browsers will react to the value changing after initial load though, it is possible they will ignore it.

Comment: Or even though the prop method, since the rows and cols IDL attributes are required to reflect their content attributes.

Answer (score -3):

```
FRAME
{
 bordercolor : #ff0000
 frameborder : yes
 border : 50
}
FRAMESET
{
 bordercolor : #00ff00
 frameborder : yes
 border : 25
 rows  : "*,250";
}
```

Comment: No. CSS is not a way of setting HTML attributes from an external file. You can only use CSS properties in CSS.